# Updating multiple users data with different values at the same time using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I'm extremely new to php programming and i'm trying to create a table which shows multiple users data, but will also allow the data within the table to be edited. Then once any changes to the data has been made I want the user to able to click an 'update' button and the new updated changes will be stored in the database. I came up with this:

```
echo "<form action=UpdateInfo.php method=post>
  <p>Edit the table below and click the update button in order to update the information.</p>";
  echo "<div id = 'table_heading'>
    <table class = 'heading'>
      <tr>
        <th class = 'odd'> Title </th>
        <th> UniID </th>
        <th class = 'odd'> First Name </th>
        <th> Surname </th>
        <th class = 'odd'> House Number </th>
        <th> Address Line One </th>
        <th class = 'address_line_two'> Address Line Two </th>
        <th> City </th>
        <th class = 'odd'> Post Code </th>
        <th> County </th>
        <th class = 'odd'> Phone Number </th>
        <th> Email </th>
        <th class = 'odd'> Username </th>
        <th class = 'far_right'> Password </th>
      </tr>
      ";
      while ($return = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))    {
        $phonenumber = "$return[PhoneNumber]";
        $number = str_pad($phonenumber, 11, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        echo "
        <tr class='data'>
          <td class = 'title'><input class = 'title' type='text' name='title' value= '".$return['Title']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'uniid'><input class = 'uniid' type='text' name='uniid' value= '".$return['UniID']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'first_name'><input class = 'first_name' type='text' name='firstname' value= '".$return['FirstName']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'surname'><input class = 'surname' type='text' name='surname' value= '".$return['Surname']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'house_number'><input class = 'house_number' type='text' name='housenumber' value= '".$return['HouseNumber']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'address_line_one'><input class = 'address_line_one' type='text' name='addresslineone' value= '".$return['AddressLineOne']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'address_line_two'><input class = 'address_line_two' type='text' name='addresslinetwo' value= '".$return['AddressLineTwo']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'city'><input class = 'city' type='text' name='city' value= '".$return['City']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'postcode'><input class = 'postcode' type='text' name='postcode' value= '".$return['PostCode']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'county'><input class = 'county' type='text' name='county' value= '".$return['County']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'phonenumber'><input class = 'phonenumber' type='text' name='phonenumber' value= '" .$number. "' /></td>
          <td class = 'email'><input class = 'email' type='text' name='email' value= '".$return['Email']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'username'><input class = 'username' type='text' name='username' value= '".$return['Username']."' /></td>
          <td class = 'password'><input class = 'password' type='text' name='password' value= '".$return['Password']."' /></td>
        </tr>";    
      }
      echo "</table>
      <input class='submit' type='submit' value='Update Info' />
    </form>
  </div>";
```

This creates the table as I had hoped and allows the data within to be edited. However when the update button is clicked and the user is taken to the 'updateinfo.php' page the following query is performed:

```
$sql = "UPDATE completeinfo SET Title='".$_POST['title']."',
FirstName='".$_POST['firstname']."',
Surname='".$_POST['surname']."',
AddressLineOne='".$_POST['addressone']."',
AddressLineTwo='".$_POST['addresstwo']."',
County='".$_POST['county']."',
City='".$_POST['city']."',
PostCode='".$_POST['postcode']."',
Email='".$_POST['email']."',
Username='".$_POST['username']."',
Password='".$_POST['password']."',
UserType='".$_POST['usertype']."'";
```

This query here updates all users in the database to have the same values as the last user to be printed out in the loop, rather than just applying the specific changes I make to each users data. I know why this is happening but I have no idea how I can achieve what am I after. Does anyone know how I can possibly have a table which holds multiple users information but each users data can be edited and updated on an individual bases rather than having all users given the same values. 
Sorry for any lack of clarity and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Before you take another step, go read up on sql injection, prepared statements, and the deprecation of mysql_ methods.

Comment: This is dangerously littered with **severe** [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). I hope this isn't on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that `UniID` is a unique identifier (primary key). If it isn't then just replace `UniID` with whatever the primary key is for that table.

```
    echo "
    <tr class='data'>
      <td class = 'title'><input class = 'title' type='text' name='title[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['Title']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'uniid'><input class = 'uniid' type='text' name='uniid[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['UniID']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'first_name'><input class = 'first_name' type='text' name='firstname[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['FirstName']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'surname'><input class = 'surname' type='text' name='surname[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['Surname']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'house_number'><input class = 'house_number' type='text' name='housenumber[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['HouseNumber']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'address_line_one'><input class = 'address_line_one' type='text' name='addresslineone[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['AddressLineOne']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'address_line_two'><input class = 'address_line_two' type='text' name='addresslinetwo[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['AddressLineTwo']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'city'><input class = 'city' type='text' name='city[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['City']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'postcode'><input class = 'postcode' type='text' name='postcode[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['PostCode']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'county'><input class = 'county' type='text' name='county[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['County']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'phonenumber'><input class = 'phonenumber' type='text' name='phonenumber[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '" .$number. "' /></td>
      <td class = 'email'><input class = 'email' type='text' name='email[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['Email']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'username'><input class = 'username' type='text' name='username[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['Username']."' /></td>
      <td class = 'password'><input class = 'password' type='text' name='password[".$return['UniID']."]' value= '".$return['Password']."' /></td>
    </tr>";

<?php

    foreach($_POST['uniid'] as $userID)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE completeinfo
        SET Title='".$_POST['title'][$userID]."',
            FirstName='".$_POST['firstname'][$userID]."',
            Surname='".$_POST['surname'][$userID]."',
            AddressLineOne='".$_POST['addressone'][$userID]."',
            AddressLineTwo='".$_POST['addresstwo'][$userID]."',
            County='".$_POST['county'][$userID]."',
            City='".$_POST['city'][$userID]."',
            PostCode='".$_POST['postcode'][$userID]."',
            Email='".$_POST['email'][$userID]."',
            Username='".$_POST['username'][$userID]."',
            Password='".$_POST['password'][$userID]."',
            UserType='".$_POST['usertype'][$userID]."'
        WHERE UniID = '".$_POST['uniid'][$userID]."'";

        // Execute your $sql here
    }
?>
```

Now, that being said, it is absolutely terrible practice to inject form data into SQL statements like this.  You should cleanse/sanitize/escape the values first, and it would also be good to parameterize them using prepared statements.

Comment: Edited after a bad copy/paste job in the HTML part.

Comment: I'm using this piece of code to check the query is working        if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))   
    {
        die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($sql));
    }                                                                However when I try to implement what you have suggested I receive an 'error' message but no error message. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need to have a WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement.  Without a where clause, the update statement always updates all the rows.  Similar to SELECT selecting all rows if you do not use a WHERE clause.

If usernames are unique, you can do the update like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='username_orig' value= '".$return['username']."' />
```

and the sql like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE completeinfo SET 
Title='".$_POST['title']."', 
FirstName='".$_POST['firstname']."',
Surname='".$_POST['surname']."', 
AddressLineOne='".$_POST['addressone']."',
AddressLineTwo='".$_POST['addresstwo']."', 
County='".$_POST['county']."', 
City='".$_POST['city']."',
PostCode='".$_POST['postcode']."', 
Email='".$_POST['email']."', 
Username='".$_POST['username']."',
Password='".$_POST['password']."', 
UserType='".$_POST['usertype']."'"
. "WHERE username = " $_POST['username_orig'];
```

username_orig would be a hidden field in your form, value set to username before the update.  Or, you can not include username as an updatable field, but make it a hidden field in the form.

Do the records in the table have keys, beside the username?  After trying a lot of approaches, I can recommend always having a primary key field in every table set to autoincrement.  That way, it always is an integer and reliably available to identify the record to be updated.  Again, you would have the record key in the form as a hidden field, like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='recordKey' value= '".$return['recordKey']."' />

And the SQL like this:
$sql="UPDATE completeinfo SET 
Title='".$_POST['title']."', 
FirstName='".$_POST['firstname']."',
Surname='".$_POST['surname']."', 
AddressLineOne='".$_POST['addressone']."',
AddressLineTwo='".$_POST['addresstwo']."', 
County='".$_POST['county']."', 
City='".$_POST['city']."',
PostCode='".$_POST['postcode']."', 
Email='".$_POST['email']."', 
Username='".$_POST['username']."',
Password='".$_POST['password']."', 
UserType='".$_POST['usertype']."'"
. "WHERE recordKey = " $_POST['recordKey'];
```

fyi, the form tag needs quotation marks around post and action, like this

```
<form action='updateInfo.php' method='post'>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with using a WHERE clause is that it is impossible to know what the clause should specify. For instance multiple users might be edited at once and all have different columns edited with different values so simply adding a WHERE clause will not distinguish between which users receive which values etc.

Comment: You can let php/sql update all the records in the form.  If the records are unchanged, the updates don't affect anything.  It just updates the values to what they are already.  In that case, MySQL does not even apply the updates, recognizing the data is unchanged.  Letting MySQL run the updates on unchanged data is fast and easy.  You can use js to update a field if any of the fields have changed in a record, then use that to update only changed records.  I let the computer do the extra work of just updating eveyrthing, changed or not.

Comment: user3298004, how is the answer you accepted getting around the objection you raised regarding the where clause?

Comment: I have tried the method you suggested as I have a field in my table set to autoincrement called 'id' so simply replacing where you have 'recordkey' with 'id' I thought I could test your strategy out. However it still does not as all the form seems to be doing is passing the values of the last instance of the loop. Therefore setting all of the users values to the same as the last users. This is why I feel if I can implement it correctly (which I have been unable to do currently) a foreach loop around the SQL statement would update each users data separately.

Comment: Good catch.  To fix, append to field names in form _<?= return['id'?> .  So if id=34, fields in form and in the post for that person all end in _34, like firstname_34, surname_34, etc.. The update then says "set " . substr($fieldname, 0, strpos($fieldname, '_')-1) . "='" . $_POST['substr($fieldname, 0, strpos($fieldname, '_')-1)'] . "'";

Comment: I think this will solve the problem I just cant get the code to work, I'm extremely new to php so bare with me but could you please explain exactly what your doing with the final piece of code? Thanks a lot for the help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was trying to show how to use id on field names and post field names.  Did you get your system working with the answer you accepted?

Comment: I understand the principle. Adding a unique ID which will change with each iteration of the while loop so when the update query is performed each different users set of data can be distinguished. I haven't got the system working as of yet though coz I cant get the update query to work correctly still.

Comment: if you send me your code and an export .sql file of the table(s) in your database connected to this, I will get it working and post the result here.  My email is stack@houstonwebsites.org  That will be the easiest way.  The code is here, but it takes awhile to make the table, load with data, etc..  If you can send the code with the tables, I think I can post working code in a short time.

Comment: Hi, did you send anything?  Just wondering, in case I missed it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. At the moment I've came up with a solution where admin can search for a user and a single users data is returned at a time. However I will be looking to fix the original solution soon I will post the files you have requested ASAP.

Comment: Thanks man.  Looking forward to completing the code for this.  Best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is want you want but I think you need to use a unique field from your table to specify the record you want to update. For that you need to modify your update query to include a where clause. For eg. say we assume that Username is a unique field, your update query will be something like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE completeinfo SET Title='".$_POST['title']."', FirstName='".$_POST['firstname']."',
    Surname='".$_POST['surname']."', AddressLineOne='".$_POST['addressone']."',
    AddressLineTwo='".$_POST['addresstwo']."', County='".$_POST['county']."', City='".$_POST['city']."',
     PostCode='".$_POST['postcode']."', Email='".$_POST['email']."', Username='".$_POST['username']."',
    Password='".$_POST['password']."', UserType='".$_POST['usertype']."' WHERE Username='".$_POST['username']."'";
```

Comment: The problem with using a WHERE clause is that it is impossible to know what the clause should specify. For instance multiple users might be edited at once and all have different columns edited with different values so simply adding a WHERE clause will not distinguish between which users receive which values etc.

Comment: In that case, what you can do is add a check box to each row and add the unique value(id, username or any other field) to it. This way when user clicks on update button to update multiple records, you will have an array of unique values. Use this array to dynamically form the where clause of your update statement. You can even loop through the array to update each record separately. Only those records will be updated which will be checked by the user.

Comment: @Hemant Why should the user have to take an extra step? If I've changed the values, then I want them updated, no? A prompt upon clicking the Update button may be helpful (to confirm that changes are desired), but having to click a box for every row that you want to update is unnecessary busywork.

Comment: I was just going for a simple approach since he said he is extremely new to php . What you can do is use JavaScript to keep track of all records edited by the user and then use this data to update your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need a WHERE clause in your MySQL query.

Here's a good tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp

Comment: This "answer" is incredibly unhelpful. Just adding a random `WHERE` clause isn't going to do a darn thing. If you're going to take the time to post an answer, take the time to explain what you mean, how to do it, and preferably give an example specific to the OP's case.